# How do I make a room in ejabberd without an owner?

Tags: ejabberd

I would like to use it as a public chat channel in a room without an owner.

But once the room is created, the first creator becomes the owner.

I want to make a room without an owner.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a room without an owner.

Well, you can create a room with the command create_room, and it doesn't have any owner.

> But once the room is created, the first creator becomes the owner.

For that, you can use the command set_room_affiliation. The problem is that is is to be execute by the server administrator, or by a script with permissions to execute that command. It is not automatically executed, and a user cannot execute it.